# Does kivy has some function which could turn an app into widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

For example I have made a custom app for file browser. Now the problem is, I  want to use that app as a widget in my another  app so i can browse files on that another app.

Is it possible to do it ? If yes, what is the best way ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have created the file browser as a widget at the beginning.

It's a good practice to leave the main App class alone, and put all app logic into custom widgets, which could be later used as modules in future apps. Only the most general app behaviors should be contained there.

Your best choice right now is rewriting your file browser as a seperate widget - if you still want to keep it.